# How can i use applescript to move from tabs in web page's form window?

Tags: javascript, applescript

im trying to do a basic applescript that move from one tab to another in a web page form. But can't find the right way and im asking for help.

This is the web page (part) code:

```
    <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="formContainer">
        <input type="hidden" id="impuestosValida" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" id="infoAduaValida" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" id="cuentaValida" value="1">
    <form id="formularioConcepto" novalidate="novalidate" method="post" data-title="Concepto">
        <div id="advertenciaConceptos" class="alert alert-warning" style="display:none;">
            <strong>¡Advertencia!</strong>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <ul id="tabsConcepto" class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabConceptos" onclick="validaEdicion(this);">Concepto</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabImpuestos" style="" onclick="deshabilitaBotonAceptar();">Impuestos</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabInfoAduanera" style="display:none;" onclick="deshabilitaBotonAceptar();">Información aduanera</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabCuentaPredial" style="display:none;" onclick="deshabilitaBotonAceptar();">Cuenta predial</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Im trying to do with "do JavaScript", but at this point, im now just guessing with something like this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('formContainer').childNodes[0].click()" in document 1
end tell
```

Any ideas? Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can’t tell because I don’t see the whole HTML, but I assume you’re trying to click the li tags under the "tabConcepto" ul which would change the tab.

In that case you should change the javascript line to:

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementById('tabsConcepto').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click()" in document 1
```

Change the 0 to which number tab you want to active. Remember to turn on "Allow JavaScript from Apple Events" under Safari’s Develop menu to allow this to run.